# See app background processes in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Maybe I'm just missing it but is there a way to view WHAT is running in the background on-device in android studio?

I'm getting a battery usage alert on my phone (galaxy s8 - OS v8.0), indicating my app is doing something in the background and I'd like to see what it is.

Thank you

Comment: Put log messages within your app where you are using Android components that gets triggered in the background, for instance: Services class, AsynTask, Activities with No layout, et cetera. Looking for these class, it should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, via the terminal function. This is one of options at the bottom of the Android studio.
You need to run ADB to connect to the device. Once connected you can use Unix command lines to see the processes running.

From google dev : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Also, the command I use to connect an emulator to run unix commands is:

```
adb -s <DEVICE> shell
```

Normally the ADB is stored :

USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

and then once connected you can use the following to see the running processes :

https://www.howtogeek.com/107217/how-to-manage-processes-from-the-linux-terminal-10-commands-you-need-to-know/

Hope this helps.